# Execute NormalModule at build time, after it is built by loaders, then save to json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am coding a plugin that, for specific modules, will try to execute the module generated at build time in order to save the result to a json file.

For that, I am tapping into `compilation.hooks.succeedModule`, which receives a `NormalModule` object already built. Then I am trying to eval the source replacing webpack variables like `__webpack_public_path__`.

While it kind of works, this approach feels terribly wrong. Like I am missing something.

Is there a nice way to execute modules at build time from a NormalModule object having basic access to vars like `__webpack_public_path__`? Maybe Webpack offers a better way to do these kind of things?

Comment: This does sound a bit like an antipattern. Can you explain a bit more about why you're doing this/what it accomplishes? Maybe there's another approach.

Comment: I am using responsive-loader. Similar to file-loader, it works with images to generate responsive versions. It basically emits different resolution files to the dist folder, then returns a module that exports an object with information of those files and resolutions.

While you would usually read that object at javascript runtime, in my case, I need that resolution info at server side (PHP), thus I am trying to export it to a json file that I can load in the server code. That's why I need to parse those modules at build time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, yeah, sounds like you can solve this another way, I've done similar stuff where I needed to change what a module output, write stuff to disk, trigger side effects, etc. It sounds like you want loaders rather than a plugin. The `run-loader` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-run-loader) executes the module it loads and exports or returns the result.

You can write a custom loader that you chain to run after `responsive-loader`, and `run-loader`, and which receives the JSON from `run-loader` and writes it to disk where you want it (as a side effect), and then returns an empty string so that nothing is added to the build. The end result would be that requiring this module in your app gets your image files created (by `responsive-loader`), and the JSON written out to disk where you need it (by your custom loader). Alternately you could skip `run-loader` and in your custom loader use regex to just grab the JSON from the output of `responsive-loader`. Using regex on code generated by a project dependency seems fragile, but as long as you have your dependency versions locked down it can work just fine in practice, and it's a bit simpler conceptually than adding `run-loader` to the pipeline.

If you're writing webpack plugins I imagine you're comfortable writing loaders as well, but if not they're pretty straightforward -- just a function that accepts source code from the loader that came before it and returns code, and does whatever you want in between. The docs aren't bad for the API, but looking at the source of a few published loaders is helpful, too. It might look roughly (just spitballing from memory) like:

```
// img-info-logging-loader.js
// regex version, expects source arg to be output of responsive-loader
import * as fs from 'fs';

export const imgInfoLoggingLoader = (source) => {
  const jsonFinderRegex = /someregexto(match)onsource/;
  const desiredJSON = source;
  const matchArr = jsonFinderRegex.exec(desiredJSON);
  if (!matchArr[1]) {
    throw new ReferenceError('json output not found in loader source.');
  } else {
    const imgConfigJsonString = matchArr[1];

    // you would write a fn to generate a filename based on the 
    // source, or based on the module's filename, which is available
    // via the webpack loader api
    const fileNameToWrite = getFileNameTowrite(); 

    try {
      // async might be preferable depending on your webpack 
      // performance needs
      fs.writeFileSync(fileNameToWrite, imgConfigJsonString); 
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(`error writing ${fileNameToWrite}`);
    }
  }

  // what the loader inserts into your JS asset: empty string
  return ''; 
}
```

EDIT:
Since per your comment you are looking to output a single JSON object with all of the image info in it, you would want a slightly different approach that does use a plugin (this is the most elegant way I know to do it, there may be others). As far as I know a plugin is the only way to 'do something' when webpack is done loading modules.

1. You still want a custom loader that is extracting the JSON from the output of the `responsive-loader`, as described above. It won't write each to disk, though. Instead your loader will call a method on the following module:
2. You also write a `json-collector.js` that is just a little node module that you will use to hold on to the JSON object you're building. This bit is awkward because it's separate from the loader but the loader needs it. This collector module is simple, though, and if you wanted to be cleaner you could turn it into a more generic module and treat it as a proper, separate node dependency. All it is is an object with a method for adding JSON data, which appends it to an internal JSON object, and one for reading out the collected data, which returns the JSON.
3. And then you have a plugin that hooks into the end of the build (I think there's one for 'build sealed' that I've used). When that hook is reached, you know webpack has no more modules to load, so the plugin now calls the 'read' method on the `json-collector`, gets the JSON object from it and writes that to disc.

This solution doesn't fit the standalone plugin/standalone loader convention in webpack but if that doesn't bother you it's actually pretty straightforward, each of the three pieces has a simple job to do. I've used this pattern multiple times and it's worked for me.

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but wouldn't this write a file for each image? What I need is one single json file with all files mapped to their objects, much like the manifest plugin, but with objects instead of paths.
I imagine I could set a file name in the options of my loader and append to that file, but how would I know when the compiler is done with all files in order to close the output file? Should I tap into a compiler hook? Can this be done inside a loader?

Comment: @CGodo Ah, I understand. Yes, in this case I would go with a plugin and a loader that work together. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yeah I was also exploring that idea, but then, going with the plugin approach, I don't know how to prevent the module to be bundled. In a loader chain it is easy, but in a plugin... not sure what hooks would work. Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Updated. There is probably a way to do this without the loader, if you spend some time looking at webpack internals and intercepting the module src at the right point in your plugin, to transform them -- but the loader pattern is already so well suited for that part that I just pair the loader and plugin together.

Comment: Sounds good enough to me! I'll explore the json-collector approach. Accepted as answer.